# Getting "ModelBinderType is not an attribute" error after integrating autofac 3 with MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, integration, autofac

As suggested at ttps://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/MvcIntegration#Register_Model_Binders , I have put ModelBinderType attribute on my ModelBinder class. It used to work fine (at least didn't show any error) when I was on MVC3, but as soon as I upgraded my solution to MVC4, this error started coming.

Am I doing anything wrong here? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

(I am referencing Autofac.Integration.Mvc here, so there shouldn't be any question of missing references)

**Edit**:

I am registering my model binders in global.asax.cs through these statements:
         // Register Model Binders

```
 builder.RegisterModelBinders(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
                builder.RegisterModelBinderProvider();
```

And I have a model binder class DataFilterBinder which inherits from BaseBusinessObjectBinder. Later class implements IModelBInder. Class DataFilterBinder goes something like this:

```
 using Autofac.Integration.Mvc;

    [ModelBinderType(typeof(DataFilter))]
    public class DataFilterBinder: BaseBusinessObjectBInder
    {


    }
```

class BaseBusinessObjectBinder looks like this:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

public abstract class BaseBusinessObjectBinder: IModelBinder
{
 public abstract object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
}
```

Please let me know if any more code is needed.

Comment: Please show us some code.

Comment: and the stacktrace please

Answer (score 0):

I had quite the same error. In my case it was because I haven't done the migration from MVC3 to MVC 4 in the right way. You can find the instructions in *"Upgrading an ASP.NET MVC 3 Project to ASP.NET MVC 4"* section on [official website page](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes). Also don't forget to upgrade Autofac MVC integration package. It should help you.